# Increase Ganach Gas Limit from Graphic Interface

Tags: limit, truffle, ganache

I am strugguling with Ganache, I have some big tests that I want to run but it is saying : 
"X ran out of gas. Something in the constructor (ex: infinite loop) caused gas estimation to fail. Try:

- Making your contract constructor more efficient
- Setting the gas manually in your config or as a deployment parameter
- Using the solc optimizer settings in 'truffle-config.js'
- Setting a higher network block limit if you are on a
  private network or test client (like ganache)."

I already increased to max gas limit in my file truffle-config.js but it is not enough because limited to 6721975.
I saw some people talking about $ganache -cli -l 30000000 but I dont have ganache in command line.
My question is : How to change this Value ?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can't increase the gas limit, but what you can do is create a new workspace and in the initialization parameter set a higher gas limit in the "chain" module.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that, for the latest truffle version, The `truffle-config.js` is slightly updated in the compilers section, need to add `settings` attributes for optimizer. Otherwise, the optimizer will not be enabled and you will easily get the following errors:

```
"YOUR CONTRACT" ran out of gas. Something in the constructor (ex: infinite loop) caused gas estimation to fail. Try:
   * Making your contract constructor more efficient
   * Setting the gas manually in your config or as a deployment parameter
   * Using the solc optimizer settings in 'truffle-config.js'
   * Setting a higher network block limit if you are on a
     private network or test client (like ganache).
```

In the following is my `truffle-config.js` setting for your references:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...Please set your own contracts_directory and contracts_build_directory

  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: 5777, //Ganache
    }
  },

  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.4",
      settings: {    //need to add "settings" before "optimizer" for latest truffle version
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true, // enable the optimizer
          runs: 200,
        },
        evmVersion: "berlin",
      },
    },
  },
}
```